# Sum of varchar field in linq , how to do conversion

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a query in sql

```
select SUM(convert(numeric ,Sub_Key_Value)) from [dbo].[Business_Report] where Parent_Tab='Staffing' and Sub_Key_Name='BM'
```

It is running fine , I am trying to implement it using linq in c# , 
Below is the code

```
int sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Parent_Tab") == "Staffing")
                           .Where((y => y.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Name") == "BM")).Sum(z => z.Field<int>("Sub_Key_Value"));
```

Problem is , when i run this code it shows "Specified cast is not valid." Probably in section

```
Sum(z => z.Field<int>("Sub_Key_Value")
```

It is coming as string from database and cant cast it as int to get sum 

Any idea how to get sum in linq is appreciable  Thanks

Comment: What about this: `Sum(z => int.Parse(z.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value")))` or `Sum(z => Convert.ToInt32(z.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value")))`? Since the field type is `NVARCHAR`, you need a conversion to `int` before doing `Sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Field` doesn't do the conversion to `int`.

```
int sum = dt.Rows.Cast<DatRow>().Sum(r => "Staffing".Equals(r["Parent_Tab"]) 
              && "BM".Equals(r["Sub_Key_Name"]) ? Convert.ToInt32(r["Sub_Key_Value"]) : 0);
```

Comment: @Saurabh LINQ and Data extensions have a small overhead, so it's a bit faster without them

Answer (score 2):

This is happening like that because, the `Sub_Key_Value` in the databases may not be of type integer or else it cannot be convertible to an integer. Let the column is of type `Varchar`, and we are applying the above query. Now we can access that column value using `.Field<string>` but `Sum()` expect some numeric values so we have to convert them to integer by using some conversion mechanisms. Here is a sample code for you:

```
.Sum(z => int.Parse(z.Field<string>("Sub_Key_Value"))
```